# host key verification failed

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I upgraded the Turtlebot laptop to Ubuntu 12.04 and ROS Fuerte. After that, I tried to ssh from my workstation. It gave this error:

> @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
> @    WARNING: REMOTE HOST
> IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!     @
> @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
> IT IS POSSIBLE THAT SOMEONE IS DOING
> SOMETHING NASTY! Someone could be
> eavesdropping on you right now
> (man-in-the-middle attack)! It is also
> possible that a host key has just been
> changed. The fingerprint for the RSA
> key sent by the remote host is
> ca:e6:7b:30:7f:bf:5a:ca:fe:....
> Please contact your system
> administrator. Add correct host key in
> /home/davidchik/.ssh/known_hosts to
> get rid of this message. Offending RSA
> key in
> /home/davidchik/.ssh/known_hosts:1
> remove with: ssh-keygen -f
> "/home/davidchik/.ssh/known_hosts" -R
> 172.17... RSA host key for 172.17... has changed and you have requested strict checking.
> Host key verification failed.

How to reset this key?

Thank you very much.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/60856/host-key-verification-failed/) by [Chik](https://answers.ros.org/users/3814/chik/) on ROS Answers with karma: 229 on 2013-04-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Use `ssh-keygen -R <hostname you want to delete>`

Not ROS specific although.

---

Originally posted by [Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/87/thomas/) with karma: 4478 on 2013-04-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Chik](https://answers.ros.org/users/3814/chik/) on 2013-04-16**:
Thank you very much